# Is there a way in Android to get the current hardware keyboard modification state?

Tags: android

I am writing an app for a Honeywell EDA50K Android device (Android API 23) which is running in kiosk mode.
I am trying to give the user some feedback on the current state of the hardware keyboard (e.g shift pressed, capslock on, meta key pressed) by showing different icons, since they cannot see the notification area where such a thing would normally be displayed.

I tried to listen to global key events by overriding `dispatchKeyEvent()` in my Activities as shown below, but to no avail. The modifier/meta flags return 0x08 (shift) without distinction for every meta button pressed.

```java
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        Log.d(TAG, " ON KEYEVENT: " + event.toString());
        Log.d(TAG, " ON KEYEVENT getMetaState: " + event.getMetaState());
        Log.d(TAG, " ON KEYEVENT getModifiers: " + event.getModifiers());

        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }
```

**Hence my question: Is there a way in Android to get the current hardware keyboard modification state ?**